# TWO TABLE AND ONE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

HELP

I HAVE A QUERY WHO GIVES ME THIS, FOR EXAMPLE:

```
TICKET CAMPO
1      DPTO
1      AREA
2      DPTO
3      AREA
```

BUT I NEED TO REPRESENT THE TABLE LIKE THIS (WITH THE RESULT OF THE PREVIOUS QUERY):

```
TICKET DPTO AREA
1      SI   SI
2      SI
3           SI
```

SOMEONE KNOWS HOW TO DO THAT?
IF YOU CAN HELP ME I WILL THANK YOU

Comment: But why are you yelling at us?

Comment: could you make the question more clear?

Comment: @Valeria the question seems to be very ambiguous. and please avoid block letters everywhere! it seems like you are yelling :D

Comment: help us to help you, follow [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)

Comment: I would request you to read your question yourself and try to answer it, once you realize it makes no sense.Please go through this link on how to ask a question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I already edited my question, sorry for the letters was not my intention shout.

Comment: DON'T USE CAP LOCK.  it is better to have no caps at all than all caps.  I recommend you re ask the question without caps and also add the "query" you have that gives the first result.  without seeing that query can't possibly answer this question.

Comment: @Valeria HINT : `PIVOT`

Comment: Post the query that you have, and some idea of what the tables look like that are referenced in that query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query might look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table_you_did_not_name
```

If that is the case then you can solve the problem shown like this:

```
SELECT
  TICKET,
  CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN CAMPO='DPTO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'SI' ELSE '' END AS DPTO,
  CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN CAMPO='AREA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'SI' ELSE '' END AS AREA
FROM some_table_you_did_not_name
GROUP BY TICKET
```

You could also do this with a join or a pivot.

Comment: Can you give an example of the query with pivot

Comment: I could -- why would I?  (In a simple case like this PIVOT is actually **much** more complicated)

Comment: Ok, i was doing something wrong but now it works thank you Hogan.

Comment: @Valeria -- you're welcome good luck (and next time don't use caps!)